# MapControllers() does not find any endpoints

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-core-6.0

I just migrated from .net core 3.1 to .net 6.
My project is an WebApi.
All my controllers inherit from ControllerBase and they have an [ApiController] attribute with the appropriate [Route] attribute. The same for my endpoints.

Everything was working great in .net 3.1.

Now, all my calls ends with an 404 error.
I tried to test the new syntax, even if I don't want to at the moment, and the result is the same.
Here is my program.cs file for this test:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
builder.Services.AddControllers();
var app = builder.Build();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.Run();
```

My sdk version is the latest (aka 6.0.406).
And the Microsoft packages version is 6.0.14.

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the culprits.
The problem was caused by these two packages from legacy code that were embbed in the project :

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Analyzers" Version="2.2.0" />
```

There may be a conflict somewhere but there was no error, all my controllers endpoints where simply ignored.
Deleting them solved everything.

Answer (score 0):

If you meet the  error like: `No webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:7285/swagger`

Try the below code:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Comment: I don't see any difference except for swagger but it is not the problem here. I tried to keep the code as simple as possible

Comment: @Eric Could you share your error message?